# AutoHotkey: how to change key behaviour when specific app is in focus

Tags: windows, focus, autohotkey

I want to additionally send <kbd>CTRL+RIGHT</kbd> when I press RIGHT in case the Windows Media Player is currently in focus. What I achieved so far is that it works in case the WMP is running. How can I change the script such that it only reacts when the WMP window is currently in focus?

```
SetTimer, KeepRunning
return
KeepRunning:
  ifWinActive, "Windows Media Player"
  {
     Right::Send ^{Right}{Right}
  }
return
```

PS: I'm a total newbie regarding AutoHotkey, so any other code suggestions are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [#If](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) to create context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings.

```
#Persistent    
#If winactive("Windows Media Player")
Right::Send ^{Right}{Right}
#If
```

Comment: `#Persistent` isn't doing anything here, and don't use `#If` unless actually needed. [`#IfWinActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) is to be used here.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charme

Comment: @0x464e Could you be so kind to post the full working code when using your suggested `#IfWinActive` syntax?

Comment: `#IfWinActive, Windows Media Player` nothing more special that that. Though I'd probably match the process' executable instead of window's title, like so: `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe wmplayer.exe`

Comment: Thanks! And why is that better? By the way, do you know why the original solution doesn't work anymore when Windows Media Player is in fullscreen mode but yours with the .exe does?